# Implicit conversion from 'Object' to 'String in vb 2008

Tags: vb.net

the error show -  Implicit conversion from 'Object' to 'String'.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Main
Dim inc As Integer = 0
Dim MaxRows As Integer

Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Dim sql As String

Private Sub Main_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load  
    con.ConnectionString 
     = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DataSource=C:\Users\dell\Desktop\todolist.accdb"

    con.Open()

    sql = "SELECT * from task"
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
    da.Fill(ds, "todolist")

    con.Close()

    MaxRows = ds.Tables("todolist").Rows.Count

    lblTaskName.Text = ds.Tables("task").Rows(inc).Item(1)
    lblPriority.Text = ds.Tables("task").Rows(inc).Item(2)
    lblCreateDate.Text = ds.Tables("task").Rows(inc).Item(3)
    dtpDueDate.Text = ds.Tables("task").Rows(inc).Item(4)

End Sub
```

Comment: Append ToString() to the Item property accesses.

Answer (score 1):

That error message tells you that your code is trying to assing an object to a variable or argument that takes a string. All objects can be converted to string like Hans suggests in his comment. But it is wise to analyze whether that assignment really is what you meant to do, instead of blindly converting the type. Hans did the analyzing here for you, but bear in mind he may not be there next time.